# Choosing a new database SQL Server, mongodb, ravendb +++

Tags: sql-server, mongodb, couchdb, ravendb, database

Currently I am starting av new project and considering which database technology I want to use. We have very good knowledge on SQL Server, but also started a couple of projects on RavenDB in 2012.

Are there any one who could help me get some arguments on pros/cons on technologies like raven, mongo, couch etc. vs. SQL Server.

I am afraid these new technologies is just a hype, or already dying out as it at least seems like that for Couchdb. Should these only be used as a sandbox for playing around with new technologies and concepts, or are they fit for the future?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, what **kind** of data do you have?

If it's rather clearly and **highly structured** (like book keeping / ledger, or order entry) -> then a "traditional" SQL database with a schema and transactions etc. certainly has clear advantages.

Or is it more **unstructured** and can take on various shapes -> then a NoSQL document-based solution like RavenDB might be worth checking out.